# Monaca / Onsen 2.0 - Charts libraries not working (SVG and Canvas) in <ons-navigator>

Tags: javascript, svg, nvd3.js, onsen-ui, monaca

So I followed this tutorial: https://onsen.io/blog/charts-angularjs-hybrid-app-nvd3/ and I cannot get the charts to render in the emulator or on the device via the debugger. I have tried Charts.JS as well as NVD3 without success.  For this question, I am trying NVD3. My code is as follows:

Index.html - head:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css">
<script src="lib/js/D3_Chart.js"></script>
```

Index.html - body:

```
<ons-template id="gameon.html">
    <ons-page>
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="center">Game On!</div>
        </ons-toolbar> 
        <ons-navigator id="gameNavigator">
            <ons-page>
                <ons-list modifier="inset">
                    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">Page 1</ons-list-item>
                    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">Page 2</ons-list-item>
                </ons-list>                    
                <ons-button>Above Chart</ons-button>
                <div id='chart2'>
                    <svg> </svg>
                </div>
                <ons-button>Below Chart</ons-button>
            </ons-page>
        </ons-navigator>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

D3_Chart.js:

```
  nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
      .x(function(d) { return d.label })
      .y(function(d) { return d.value })
      .showLabels(true)     //Display pie labels
      .labelThreshold(.05)  //Configure the minimum slice size for labels to show up
      .labelType("percent") //Configure what type of data to show in the label. Can be "key", "value" or "percent"
      .donut(true)          //Turn on Donut mode. Makes pie chart look tasty!
      .donutRatio(0.35)     //Configure how big you want the donut hole size to be.
      ;

    d3.select("#chart2 svg")
        .datum(exampleData())
        .transition().duration(350)
        .call(chart);

  return chart;
});

//Pie chart example data. Note how there is only a single array of key-value pairs.
function exampleData() {
  return  [
      { 
        "label": "One",
        "value" : 29.765957771107
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Two",
        "value" : 0
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Three",
        "value" : 32.807804682612
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Four",
        "value" : 196.45946739256
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Five",
        "value" : 0.19434030906893
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Six",
        "value" : 98.079782601442
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Seven",
        "value" : 13.925743130903
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Eight",
        "value" : 5.1387322875705
      }
    ];
}
```

I have tried different syntax on the data because the example has a few different forms, but all do not generate a chart.  I am not using AngularJS.

I have confirmed this code works in Chrome and in the default browser on Android, but not on Monaca.  Additionally, I was worried about domain issues so I have also tried with the referenced JS and CSS files downloaded and added to the project.  No errors are generated, just the chart does not show.

Edit:  Updated to explicitly show the `<ons>` tags as commented below.  The point is, the code works fine in Chrome and Android browser (I would assume iOS as well, just don't have access to test.) but it fails to execute in a Monaca / Onsen 2.0 project.  The code is from the Onsen Blog, which leads me to wonder if 2.0 breaks this functionality.

Answer:  As I posted in the comment below, the issue is not with Onsen but how/when the objects are added to the DOM.  This post provides the specifics:  [Onsen 2.0 - Adding event listener to Ons-Switch with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123385/onsen-2-0-adding-event-listener-to-ons-switch-with-javascript)

Comment: are you using onsen-ui at all, i don't see any ons-tags.

Comment: Updated the question to show you tags.

Comment: It works for me on the phone, i did it in codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeqMEJ. Afterwards i did a project and used monaca upload and i was able to see it on my android phones, maybe you have an old android phone that does not support svg?

Comment: New phone - Galaxy S6.  I copied your code and it works now.  I must have had something out-of-wonk, even though I copied from Monaca IDE to stackoverflow.  I tried placing the svg below a <ons-list> that is in a <ons-navigator> and that causes it to go to a side page that isn't swipable completely, if that makes sense.  Regardless, it's working now!  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for answering.  I just learned that the templates aren't loaded like I thought. Fran Dios posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123385/onsen-2-0-adding-event-listener-to-ons-switch-with-javascript  The answer to a different problem but they share the same root cause.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this is another post:

```
document.addEventListener("init", function(event) {
  if (event.target.id == "my-page") {
    document.getElementById("my-switch").addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      console.log('click', e);
    });
  }
}, false);
```