# Run process before load page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, onsen-ui

i am using cordova 6 with onsen-ui,jquery and javascript. So i am trying to make a simple login site, but i need to get if gps is active. I want to know WHERE i must do that validation. Now I do the following on ons.ready() event.

```
var options = {maximumAge: 0, timeout: 3000, enableHighAccuracy:true};
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGPSCheckSuccess, onGPSCheckError, options);

function onGPSCheckSuccess()
{
    console.log("Encontro el GPS Activado");
}

function onGPSCheckError()
{
    console.log("Error al chequear el GPS");
    gpsDetect.switchToLocationSettings(onSwitchToLocationSettingsSuccess,     onSwitchToLocationSettingsError);
}

function onSwitchToLocationSettingsSuccess() {
}

function onSwitchToLocationSettingsError(e) {
  console.log("Error al activar el GPS");
  alert("Error onSwitchToLocationSettingsError: "+e);
}
```

So if there a way to do this BEFORE my main page es loaded?

Regards

Comment: check device ready here -- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do this, it with the following code:

```
document.addEventListener("init", function(event){
    if(event.target.id=='yourHomePageID') {
      var options = {maximumAge: 0, timeout: 3000, enableHighAccuracy:true};
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGPSCheckSuccess, onGPSCheckError, options);
    }
},false);
```

By using the init function for the homepage, this actually runs a bit before `ons.ready()` as discussed here by @fran-dios:

[Onsen 2.0 - Adding event listener to Ons-Switch with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123385/onsen-2-0-adding-event-listener-to-ons-switch-with-javascript)

Hope this helps.  It is what I am doing based on the aforementioned question and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do a simple page redirect. You can have that code in a `.htm` file, which you call before your page. When this succeeds, you then store the result using `localStorage`,  then redirect to the page you want, and retrieve the results from `localStorage`.

Comment: Thank you, your idea is very interesting. I should think about it before. Thank you so much.

Comment: It's pleasure to be helpful.